# "How it looks like"

Tags: grammar, phrasing

My German English professor regularly uses the phrase "how it looks like", for example in questions.

> How does the social media market look like today?

In my head, it always sounds wrong – I'd rather use "what it looks like" or "how it looks".

> What does the social media market look like today?
>
> How does the social media market look today?

Which of the three usages are correct?

Comment: As a native speaker I agree with you entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An interrogative phrase *How* replaces the preposition phrase including any prepositions:

- **How** [does it look <s>**like something**</s>]?

An interrogative phrase with *What* just replaces a noun phrase:

- **What** [does it look like <s>**something**</s>]?

So, in short, the Original Poster's intuitions are correct. If we try to use *How* but not delete the preposition, the sentence will be ungrammatical:

- *How does it look like? (ungrammatical - *like* should be deleted)